# How to grab a file from django select DocumentForm?

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-templates, dajax

I have a select form in django templates:

```
        <form action="{% url "graph" document.docfile.name %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="{{ document.docfile.name }}" id="{{ document.docfile.name }}" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value=""></option>
        {% for document in documents %}
        <option value="{{ document.docfile.name }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </form>
```

I want to pick the selected file in views.py. I tried request.POST.get() with no success:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   doc = request.POST.get("name", "")
```

How can I grab the name of the selected file in python views.py?

Comment: Your generated HTML is not valid. You can't have more than one `selected` option in a select element. But in order for us to answer, you'll need to actually post the Ajax code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I edit the html form and now I think it works. But I still can't grab the selected file in views.py...